# Why GMail is showing Bcc addresses?

Tags: gmail

Today I receive an answer from Tissot, with my surprise I noticed that the Bcc field is clearly visible to me, showing other supposedly hidden recipients:

[Bcc recipient visible in a received email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9f7V.jpg)

The Picture show Cnn which is italian equivalent to Bcc. This is rather creepy as I also at times use Bcc feature, and if GMail started to show Bcc recipients might be a problem.

Comment: IIRC it's up to the source mail server to strip out the header yet deliver the mail to the specified recipients.

Comment: Which email address is shown in the BCC field? Is it your own, the sender, or a third party?

Comment: @slhck it is Tissot other address, not the From one, and I'm not included in the Bcc also I read that sometimes GMail show Bcc when you are part of a group, but this doesn't seem to be the case.